# ASP.net scriptmanager and AJAX control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

im making a username availability check in ASP.net using ajax updatepanel, but i keep getting the following error

**The control with ID 'UserNameUP' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.]**

im using the create user wizard, to create a new user but i want to check if the user already exists, i have the following code in the aspx file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UserNameUP">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true"  OnTextChanged="Username_Changed"></asp:TextBox></ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel><br />
```

but i keep getting that error, can any one help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your update panel, make sure you have a scriptmanager:

```
   <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: do i not put anything in the asp:ScriptManager ?? im getting a new error now 
"Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page." but the thing is i dont have another instance !!

Comment: Look through the aspx page and double check that there isn't a second ScriptManager somewhere below your update panel.

Comment: i moved the asp:ScriptManager to the top of the form, just after  <form id="form1" runat="server">, but now im having a problem with the OnTextChanged="Username_Changed" not being called, any ideas ??

Comment: If you read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx the postback will only occur when the textbox loses focus.  It won't postback everytime the value of the textbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a script manager inside a master page? That can cause the "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page" error?

Or, if its DNN, there is one on each "page" by default.